# Angular App not compiling

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular6

I am trying to create a simple Angular app and I am trying to use `ngrx` so I can use states. I was initially in my app folder and ran the command `yarn add @ngrx/store`.

Whenever I try to import the `StoreModule` using `import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store'` at the top of my `app.module.ts` file I receive a compilation error (listed below).

```
ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/actions_subject.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"...AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '".../AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.  
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '".../AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/scanned_actions_subject.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '".../AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/state.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '".../AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/state.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '".../AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '".../AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/Observer"' has no exported member 'Observer'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '".../AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '".../AngularProjects/ngrx-tut/node_modules/rxjs/Operator"' has no exported member 'Operator'.
node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/BehaviorSubject'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observer.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observer'.
node_modules/rxjs/Operator.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Operator'.
node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subject'.
```

I am able to `import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'` on a different file and I don't have receive any errors.

I appreciate any help and/or comments!

**EDIT:**

I included `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` but I am still getting these errors.

Comment: Can you please provide version of ngrx, rxjs & angular

Comment: Running a `yarn check` shows `error "@ngrx/store##@angular/core@^5.0.0" doesn't satisfy found match of "@angular\\core@6.0.2"`. Maybe I need to update my rxjs and my ngrx

Comment: Yes Most probably its issue with incompatible version of those three... please check... otherwise provide versions you are using i will take a look

Comment: Angular - 6.0.2, rxjs - 6.1.0, @ngrx/store - 6.0.0-beta.0

Comment: Versions you provided above are compatible it should work... If you are still facing this issue please install rxjs-compat that should help... But please try to avoid since you are already in latest version of these libs and starting a new app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here were my dependencies at the beginning of this question:

```
Angular - 6.0.2 | rxjs - 6.1.0 | @ngrx/store - 1.X
```

My issue was that my `@ngrx/store` was on `1.X` and everything else I had was on `6.X`. I updated @ngrx/store to v6.0.0-beta.3 and it works now.

> I initially installed @ngrx/store using the `yarn` command. *Does that mean that using yarn will give everyone a v1.x verison by default?* I hope not..

Anyways, thanks everyone for your help!